# Meaning of processing controller_name as */* in rails logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting following in my production logs.

```
Processing by Foo::FoosController#robots as */*
```

In normal cases I see html or json or xml in place of `*/*`.

I wanted to know that what does that `*/*` means ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`as */*` shows the accept header used by the client for the request. Robots generally sets the accept header to `*/*` which essentially means "Dear server give my back the response in whatever content type you want according to your preference".

More details [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html#z3).

> an asterisk "*" may be used in place of either the second half of the content-type value, or both halves. This only applies to the Accept: filed, and not to the content-type field of course.
>
> ```
> Accept:  *.*, q=0.1
> Accept:  audio/*, q=0.2
> Accept:  audio/basic q=1
> ```